# Time spent to execute code in prepareForSegue longer than the one spent till the end of viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two `UIViewController`. I call the second one by using a segue in the first one. Here is some code I'm using in the `prepareForSegue` method of the first controller in order to check how long takes the execution of `...some code`:

```
let start = NSDate()
userDefaults.setObject(start, forKey: "startDate")

...some code

let end = NSDate()
let timeSpentInSegue = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start) * 1000
println("time Spent In Segue : \(timeSpentInSegue)")
```

In my second `UIViewController`, in the `viewWillAppear` method, I just wrote:

```
let startDate = userDefaults.objectForKey("startDate") as! NSDate
let now = NSDate()
println("appeared in: \(now.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate))")
```

the startDate is the same one I used in the segue of the first `UIViewController`.

Here is what I got in the console output when I go from the first to the second controller in my app:

```
time Spent In Segue : 0.97203254699707
appeared in: 0.0576500296592712
```

I don't understand why I spent more time in the segue than I spent in "segue + loading of the 2nd view controller". It doesn't make sense.

Can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying to find a place to hide myself... I just forgot to multiply `timeIntervalSinceDate` by 1000 in viewWillAppear... Should I delete the question?

Comment: Is that what solved your issue? Or did either of the answers help you?

Comment: Actually it's when I printed out the time of entry and exit in/of both methods that I realised my mistake.

Comment: According to icaro, and myself, you're still grabbing your timestamps at the incorrect times.

Answer (score 1):

This is because during the segue, `viewWillAppear` is called almost immediately so that it can setup your next view BEFORE it appears. This is so that your elements on the next screen don't "pop" in to view when the segue is over.

Try running the code you have placed in `viewWillAppear` inside `viewDidAppear` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two main reason are:

1. You are creating, Initializing and setting some properties of the
   second controller in the first controller, so some time for the second view controller creating is been counted in the first counter
2. The "life cycle" for a `UIViewController` is `ViewDidLoad`, `ViewWillAppear`, `ViewDidAppear`. So try measure the time from `ViewDidLoad` to `ViewDidAppear`

Note: The total time expend will not be a combination of the two as `ViewDidLoad` is called when the object get created, so the two timers will run in parallel for a while, because you are using `NSDate` you will be able to actually see the overlap of the two.

Comment: Yes I guess it wouldn't be the same but I didn't understand why the first one would be smaller... but I figured it out... see my comment... Thanks anyway